# YII2 unknown `with` and `joinWith` on joining two tables

Tags: php, yii2

I have two related tables and I wanted to join them but I get the following error:

> Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling
>   unknown method: backend\models\TblSubProject::joinWith()'

Here is the relation...

```
public function getBrgyCode()
{
    return $this->hasOne(LibBrgy::className(), ['brgy_code' => 'brgy_code']);
}
```

and here is the action...

```
public function actionGetsp()
{
  $sp_id=$_POST['sp_id'];
if (($sp = TblSubProject::findOne($sp_id)->joinWith(brgyCode)) !== null) {
        return $sp->sp_title."||";
    } else {
        return "Not Found";
    }
}
```

I am calling the action through ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findOne` method returns end result of the query - `ActiveRecord` object.

`with` and `joinWith` must be applied only to `ActiveQuery` object.

Rewrite your query for example to:

```
$subProject = TblSubProject::find()->joinWith('brgyCode')->one();
```

Also you missed quotes around the name of relation inside `joinWith`.

**Official docs:**

- [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html)
- [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html)
- [findOne()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findOne%28%29-detail)
- [with()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with%28%29-detail)
- [$joinWith](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#$joinWith-detail)

Comment: from the documentation i found a solution like this 

`$customer = Customer::findOne(123);
$orders = $customer->orders;`

But I see your answer sexier. Can I make it like this `$subProject = TblSubProject::find($sp_id)->joinWith('brgyCode')->one();`? this seems to return the first value..

Comment: Apply additional condition in `where` part: `$subProject = TblSubProject::find()->joinWith('brgyCode')->where(['sp_id' => $sp_id])->one();` And you probably don't need `joinWith` here, `with` is enough. Yes, it returns one result, for one to many relationship use `all()`. As for solution from the docs, it's OK too. Use it depending on situation. I show it with `ActiveQuery` because it was in your initial question.